How to do an insert with a column of an enum type with SimpleJdbcInsert?
I have to insert some records into my db using Jdbc. One of the columns, "type" is of a custom data type (let's call it "test_type") and that's making the insert fail.
Currently, I have this code (simplified):
    Map<String, Object> testRecord = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("name", "whatever");
        put("type", "planning");
    }};

    SimpleJdbcInsert insertTest = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate)
        .withTableName("test_table")
        .usingColumns(testRecord.keySet().toArray(new String[0]))
        .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");

    Number testId = insertTest.executeAndReturnKey(testRecord);

that gives this error:
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "type" is of type test_type but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

The query in SQL works fine, even when passing it simply as a string, so I thought it would work here too. It doesn't, obviously.
Does anyone know how I could fix this? I tried appending "::test_type" to the string but that does not seem to work either.

What is a table definition statement?

We should ensure value in map for custom data type's column should be created be before keeping in map.
test_type t1 = new test_type();
    t1.setValue("planning");
    
    
    Map<String, Object> testRecord = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("name", "whatever");
        put("type", t1);
    }};

